# Unity3d convert Texture2d into bitmap format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had made an attempt to get this done but unfortunately I am coming up short not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
private void CreateMovie(List<Texture2D> textures, string fileName, int frameRate)
{
    var writer = new AviWriter(fileName + ".avi")
    {
        FramesPerSecond = frameRate,
        EmitIndex1 = true
    };

    var stream = writer.AddVideoStream();
    stream.Width = _images[0].width;
    stream.Height = _images[0].height;
    stream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed;
    stream.BitsPerPixel = BitsPerPixel.Bpp32;

    int count = 0;

    while (count < textures.Count)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = textures[count].GetRawTextureData();
        stream.WriteFrame(false, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        count++;
    }

    writer.Close();
}
```

Once I write the bytes to file and try to open it I get the file is in a unknown format.

Comment: Seems like some helpful links to bitmap file loaders here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1308973/how-to-load-a-bmp-file-in-binary.html

Comment: Not trying to load the bitmap file rather convert Texture2d to a bitmap without the use of System.Drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code for writing to the texture?

To convert your Texture to a different format, you will need to create a new Texture with the desired format, then write the data to the texture.

Use the following constructor:
`public Texture2D(int width, int height, TextureFormat textureFormat = TextureFormat.RGBA32, bool mipChain = true, bool linear = false);`

Comment: posted the whole class

Comment: pretty cool I see there is a TextureFormat.BGRA already there so ill use that but still not sure if this will work. Fingers crossed